# how to override default values needed by function in module?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how I can override default values of functions that are defined inside some module. Consider this code (`program.py`):

```
# import the default & user defined settings
from default_settings import *
from my_settings import *

# import some functions, which might be dependent on the settings above
from functions import *

# call dummy_function from 'functions' - prints '1'
dummy_function()

# output SOME_DEFAULT - will be '1'
print SOME_DEFAULT

# re-import 'my_settings' - SOME_DEFAULT will now be '2'
from my_settings import *
print SOME_DEFAULT
```

here is `default_settings.py`:

```
DO_DEBUG = False
SOME_DEFAULT = 1
```

here is `my_settings.py`, who's values I'd like to use inside `functions.py`:

```
DO_DEBUG = True
SOME_DEFAULT = 2
```

This is `functions.py`, where I need to import `default_settings`, otherwise I get an NameError. I don't want to import `my_settings` here, because `functions.py` should be more like a generic library.

```
# if I leave this line out, then I get a 
# "NameError: name 'SOME_DEFAULT' is not defined"
from default_settings import *

# I don't want to add "from my_settings import *" here, because 'functions.py' 
# is supposed to be a generic library of functions.

# dummy decorator.
def do_profile(cond):
    def resdec(f):
        if cond:
            print "profiling!"
        return f
    return resdec


# dummy function depending on both 'DO_DEBUG' and 'SOME_DEFAULT'
@do_profile(DO_DEBUG)
def dummy_function(bla=SOME_DEFAULT):
    print bla
```

If I run `python program.py` I get the following output:

```
1
1
2
```

This is expected. The first `1` comes from `dummy_function`, the second `1` comes from the import of `default_settings` inside `functions` and the `2` is a result of me re-importing `my_settings`.

Is there a way that I can override the default settings that are needed by `dummy_function` by simply using `my_settings`? I thought about leaving out the `from default_settings import *` line in `functions`, but then I run into `NameError`. Is there a way to import from `functions` and at the same time pass on all variables into `functions`?

Comment: This post may be the best argument I've ever read for never using `from foo import *`.

Comment: whether I use `from foo import *` or `from foo import DO_DEBUG, SOME_DEFAULT` doesn't make a big difference, does it? I'll be happy to hear from you how to do things differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your settings differently. Right now, you're using two different modules as containers for two different sets of settings. Then you import all the names from those modules, counting on `from my_settings import *` to overwrite the names imported by `from default_settings import *`. That's an abuse of `import`.

In general, I'd say that the names defined when you `import` a module should *not* be redefined implicitly. `from module import *` is already bad because it implicitly defines a bunch of names in the global namespace; using *another* `*` import to implicitly *redefine* those names is just scary.

My suggestion would be to either use a dictionary to store settings, or use a settings class. In the first case, you could do something like this:

```
# settings.py
default_settings = {'foo': True, 'bar': False}
my_settings = {'foo': False}
current_settings = default_settings.copy()
current_settings.update(my_settings)
```

Now any module can `import settings` and access them like this:

```
foo = settings.default_settings['foo']
bar = settings.current_settings['bar']
settings.current_settings['bar'] = True
```

Any changes to these settings are visible to all modules that have imported `settings`.

A more complex approach might be to use a `Settings` class. `Settings` would define some defaults:

```
class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):
        self.foo = foo if foo is not None else True
        self.bar = bar if bar is not None else False
```

Now you can create various custom settings:

```
# settings.py
default_settings = Settings()
my_settings = Settings(foo=False)
current_settings = my_settings.copy()
current_settings.foo = False    # pointless example
```

And again, as above, we `import settings` to access them or make changes:

```
# foo.py
import settings
bar = settings.current_settings.bar
settings.current_settings.foo = True
```

You can even inherit from `Settings` to create new defaults:

```
class LocalSettings(Settings):
    def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):             # in Python 3, 
        super(LocalSettings, self).__init__(foo, bar)   # super().__... works
        self.foo = foo if foo is not None else True
```

And so on.

Comment: You had me at: "you need to encapsulate your settings differently" (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Your functions are defined in `functions.py` at import time -- So, if (in program.py) you

```
#start of file DO NOT "import functions" YET!!!
import default_settings
import my_settings

default_settings.DO_DEBUG=my_settings.DO_DEBUG
default_settings.SOME_DEFAULT=my_settings.SOME_DEFAULT

import functions
```

then the settings from `my_settings` should take over.  I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for (it doesn't sit right with me), but I can't see any other option with this code structure.

**edit**

To alleviate the pain of resetting all the settings by hand, you could probably use the `inspect` module:

```
#start of file DO NOT "import functions" YET!!!
import default_settings
import my_settings
import inspect

#pull out all of "my_settings" and apply them to "default_settings",
# but only if they don't start with an underscore (reserved)
members=inspect.getmembers(my_settings)
for k,v in members:
    if( not k.startswith('_') ):
        setattr(default_settings,k,getattr(my_settings,k))

import functions
```

However, This still doesn't sit right with me -- The thing I don't like is that the behavior of `functions` depends on when you import it which is not something you typically see in python.  I think your code could benefit from some sort of restructuring.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about `myfunction.py`. Regardless, a slightly cleaner way to do something like this might be to have the `default_settings` module provide a function to change some or all of its default values. If this is done before any other modules import and use it, then they'll get the reconfigured values because Python caches modules and won't actually reload and reinitialize it.

Comment: @martineau : good comment.  I'm not sure what I meant about `myfunction.py` either -- should have been `functions.py`.  And I thought about having functions in `default_settings` to reset those values too, but the thing about this code that seems dirty is that you need to set those constants *before importing anything else* due to the use of the decorators.  A better solution would be to have a factory in `functions.py` which returns a decorated or undecorated version of the function based on the flag -- then use the factory to get the function ...

Comment: @mgilson I like your solution. However I see a problem with having more than a couple of settings - it's kinda painful to manually add those line by line. Is there a better way to overwrite all definitions that are found in `my_settings` (not all of them might be defined, if the user chooses to stick with some default) automatically?

Comment: @memyself -- I've added an (untested) example of how you can inspect what is in my_settings and update accordingly.

Comment: @memyself: You could store all your setting in a dictionary and then use the `dict.update()` method to update a smaller subset of them. Python provides many way to create dictionaries which could be helpful for both initializing such a settings dictionary as well as updating it using this method.